# Sinatra Session data shared between browsers

Tags: ruby, session, heroku, sinatra

I have a basic banking application running on [Heroku](https://greenwich-banking.herokuapp.com) using Sinatra.

I have tried implementing sessions to ensure each user that visits has a different version of the app. However, at the moment, if I visit it with two separate browsers, I have the same data.

There is no backend database implemented but data I add via the interface persists in every browser I visit in.

**Here is my `app.rb`:**

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'tilt/erb'
require 'require_all'
require_all 'lib'
require 'rufus-scheduler'

class BankingApp < Sinatra::Base

  enable :sessions
  set :session_secret, 'super secret'

  get '/' do
    session[:accounts] = AccountsController.instance
    session[:holders]  = HoldersController.instance
    session[:loans]    = LoansController.instance 
    erb :index
  end

  get '/holders' do
    @holders = session[:holders].store
    erb :holders
  end

  get '/holders_accounts' do
    @holder = session[:holders].find(params[:id].to_i)
    message = session[:accounts].get_accounts_of(params[:id].to_i)
    @accounts = message.accounts
    erb :holders_accounts
  end

  get '/new_holder' do
    erb :new_holder
  end

  post '/new_holder' do
    @message = session[:holders].create(params[:name])
    @holders = session[:holders].store
    erb :holders
  end

  get '/create_account' do
    erb :create_account
  end

  post '/create_account' do
    type = :Current
    id = params[:id].to_i
    @message = session[:accounts].open(type, with: id)
    erb :index
  end

  get '/accounts' do
    @accounts = session[:accounts].store
    erb :accounts
  end

  get '/transactions' do
    message = session[:accounts].get_transactions_of(params[:id].to_i)
    @transactions = message.transactions
    erb :transactions
  end

  get '/deposit' do
    erb :deposit
  end

  post '/deposit' do
    @accounts = session[:accounts].store
    @message = session[:accounts].deposit(params[:amount].to_i, into: params[:id].to_i)
    erb :accounts
  end

  get '/withdraw' do
    erb :withdraw
  end

  post '/withdraw' do
    @accounts = session[:accounts].store
    @message = session[:accounts].withdraw(params[:amount].to_i, from: params[:id].to_i)
    erb :accounts
  end

  get '/transfer' do
    erb :transfer
  end

  post '/transfer' do
    @accounts = session[:accounts].store
    @message = session[:accounts].transfer(params[:amount].to_i, from: params[:donar].to_i, to: params[:recipitent].to_i)
    erb :accounts
  end

  get '/add_holder' do
    erb :add_holder
  end

  post '/add_holder' do
    @accounts = session[:accounts].store
    @message = session[:accounts].add_holder(params[:holder_id].to_i, to: params[:account_id].to_i)
    erb :accounts
  end

  get '/enable_overdraft' do
    erb :enable_overdraft
  end

  post '/enable_overdraft' do
    @accounts = session[:accounts].store
    @message = session[:accounts].activate_overdraft(params[:id].to_i, params[:amount].to_i)
    erb :accounts
  end

  get '/disable_overdraft' do
    erb :disable_overdraft
  end

  post '/disable_overdraft' do
    @accounts = session[:accounts].store
    @message = session[:accounts].deactivate_overdraft(params[:id].to_i)
    erb :accounts
  end

  get '/loans' do
    @loans = session[:loans].store
    erb :loans
  end

  get '/loan_view' do
    message = session[:loans].show(params[:id].to_i)
    @transactions = message.transactions
    erb :loan_view
  end

  get '/new_loan' do
    erb :new_loan
  end

  post '/new_loan' do
    @loans = session[:loans].store
    id = params[:id].to_i
    options = { borrowed: params[:amount].to_i, term: params[:term].to_i, rate: params[:rate].to_f }
    @message = session[:loans].create_loan(id, options)
    erb :loans
  end

  get '/pay_loan' do
    erb :pay_loan
  end

  post '/pay_loan' do
    @message = session[:loans].pay(params[:amount].to_i, off: params[:id].to_i)
    @loans = session[:loans].store
    erb :loans
  end

  # start the server if ruby file executed directly
  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

I do not have a great deal of experience with Sinatra so apologies if this is an oversight on my part.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to share a little more on what you're trying to achieve here, and why you're taking this approach. There's a lot going on here that isn't very idiomatic of Sinatra or Ruby, and combined with all of the code we can't see (e.g., the definitions of the controllers) it's hard to say with confidence what's broken vs what's just being implemented in a non-standard way. EDIT: Just noticed the code is on GitHub, I'll go poke around there :)

Answer (score 3):

So I'm pretty sure the core of your problem is [this line](https://github.com/robertpulson/banking_application/blob/master/lib/controllers/holders_controller.rb#L6) which you have in multiple places throughout your code. As per the [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html)

> This ensures that only one instance of Klass can be created.

You've explicitly told ruby to only ever let one copy of each class/module ever exist. I don't think that's what you want.

It's a bit hard to infer what it is you're trying to achieve exactly but I don't think using `Singleton` in a web app is going to be the right solution. The assumptions it imposes break down as soon as you run a 2nd instance (or dyno in Heroku parlance) of your app.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ive used Singleton classes so that I can reference a single instance of each controller in each of the controller. Letting the controller communicate with each other. Is there a more effective way of doing this?

Comment: @robertpulson from [the docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Request/Instance%20Scope) "For every incoming request, a new instance of your application class is created". To share data either use the [settings helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Configuration) or use a class instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this

> get '/logout' do
>
> session.clear
>
> end